# Multiple UIs in a Windows Forms program

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a window forms project, I have a login screen, a menu and a couple of other forms, I'm switching between them with:

```
this.Hide();
frm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(subFormClosed);
frm.Show();
```

and the `FormClosedEventHandler(subFormClosed);`

```
private void subFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

So the aim of this is that when a subform is closed by the user to close this.

There is however a problem, I want to go back to the menu and the issue is that I have one of two possibilites, that I can see:

1. I can pass the menu form to the subForm by reference to then show it and hide the subform - this seems to be one really really kludgy way of doing it but it would work.
2. I can just open a new version of the menu form - this would lead to huge memory issues in overuse (more instances being created and then never destroyed until the program is closed, e.g. 30 menu forms sub forms)

I was trying to use the CloseReason to check if the sub form was closed by the user or if it was closed from code, however both the exit button and `this.Close()` return `CloseReason.UserClosing`. Hence I couldn't differentate between the two types of exiting.

So basically what I'm asking for is there a better way of doing this, I've read about MDI and SDI and I can't really work out which would be applicable, or if the kludgy option 1 is the best way of doing this.

Comment: I believe the best way to manage it is really closing the forms and calling them (Show) whenever necessary - it is the normal usage of forms. But, if you NEED to keep them opened (even hidden), why don´t you just utilize the Minimize function, perhaps, without the "ShowInTaskBar" property. This way, I believe you will achieve what you want - although it´s not bright clear to me.

Comment: In your example, which form is the "menu"? If you want to show the "menu" form when some other form is closed, why can't you just use the same technique you are showing here? I.e. subscribe to the `FormClosed` event (from the "menu" code, where the first "other form" was opened) and when that "other form" closes, re-show the "menu" form. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your problem clearly, with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answer with the ShowDialog solution is a very good one, here is another way to do if for whatever reasons one does not want to use ShowDialog:

In the constructor of your menu form, use the `FormClosed` and the `Shown` events of your subforms this way:

```
subForm1.FormClosed += (s, e) => showMenu();
subForm1.Shown+= (s, e) => hideMenu();

subForm2.FormClosed += (s, e) => showMenu();
subForm2.Shown+= (s, e) => hideMenu();
...

void showMenu()
{
    this.Show();
}

void hideMenu()
{
    this.Hide();
}
```

Then you can use subForm1.Show() freely and close them the way you want: the events will be triggered accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ShowDialog and pass the menu page as the Owner. Something like this:

**In Menu**:

```
// on menu navigation button click
this.hide();
SubForm sub = new SubForm();
sub.ShowDialog(this);   // open as a dialog with this form as the owner
```

**In Sub Form**:

```
// on subform's back button click or better, in the FormClosing event
this.Owner.show();
this.Close();    // this line is not needed if implemented in FormClosing event
```

Comment: Thanks this is basically perfect